# 14.04 - USB microphone speaker device not working anymore

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, usb, kernel

I own a PJP-20UR web conference microphone speaker, I have been using this USB device for ages with Linux, Windows, Mac never ever have had any issues with it.

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 to 64-bit 14.04, this device is not working at all anymore. Please see the errors below.

How can I resolve it??? Will I always have to go back to Ubuntu 12.04 for this?

[image: PJP-20UR microphone speaker photo]

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cb1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cba
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cad
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 8ca0
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c90 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c96 (rev d0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c98 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8ca6
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8cc6
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 8c82
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 8ca2
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

$ lsusb | grep Yamaha
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0499:4018 Yamaha Corp. 



$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Aug  6 11:26:09 e300 kernel: [ 1040.906550] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8800369e8b00
Aug  6 11:26:09 e300 kernel: [ 1040.906553] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Trying to add endpoint 0x81 without dropping it.
Aug  6 11:26:09 e300 kernel: [ 1040.906555] usb 3-9: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
Aug  6 11:26:09 e300 kernel: [ 1040.906556] 4:2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-22)

$ dmesg
[ 1040.906553] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Trying to add endpoint 0x81 without dropping it.
[ 1040.906555] usb 3-9: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
[ 1040.906556] 4:2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-22)
```

Comment: Could we see all of lsusb?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8025376/ - Please find the lsusb -v form the link

Comment: I have noticed that some devices are fussy about wether you plug them into USB2 or USB3. I have upgraded my OS and it was working in the port it was plugged in and after upgrade had to plug it in a different USB. I know thats something you've probably already tried but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: In my case even i change ports its happening same.

Comment: Another idea, there is a reference to 1.07 in the lsusb output which probably referers to firmware. I noticed there is a version 1.09 of the firmware. Firmware updates are risky, depends on whether you want to take a risk.

Comment: YES - sure how and where?